# Ask for an example for the limitation of boost::bind()

Tags: c++, boost

I read the explanation of the limitation at
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/bind/bind.html#Limitations
but I don't quite understand it.
Can any body give me an example of that stated limitation, please?

Let me ask this question in another way with this example:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void Five(int &a, int &b, int &c, const int &d, const int &e) {
  cerr << "In Five(): " << a + b + c + d + e << endl;
}

int main() {
  int r = 1;
  const int c = 100;

  boost::bind(Five, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5)(r, r, r, c, r);
  boost::bind(Five, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5)(r, r, r, r, c);

  return 0;
}
```

This code compiles just fine (without C++11 support). So, if bind even works in this case, what does "limitation" refer to? Any concrete examples, please?

Another (better) example:

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void Two(int &a, const int &c) {
  cerr << "In Two(): " << a + c << endl;
}

void Three(int &a, int &b, const int &c) {
  cerr << "In Three(): " << a + b + c << endl;
}

int Fun() { return 3; }

int main() {
  int r = 1;
  const int c = 100;
  boost::bind(Two, _1, _2)(r, Fun());           // 1. OK
  boost::bind(Three, _1, _2, _3)(r, r, c);      // 2. OK
  Three(r, r, Fun());                           // 3. OK
  boost::bind(Three, _1, _2, _3)(r, r, Fun());  // 4. CE!!
  //??? Why 2 is OK but 4 is not ???

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limitation refer to "perfect forwarding", that is implemented on recent compilers by enabling c++0x (can require some options at compile-time).

So boost::bind use the perfect-forwarding if your compiler support c++0x, else ignore the problem to avoid an explosion of function overloading!

For example: the functor object created by boost::bind when binding a function with 2 arguments will require all this overloads (if there is no c++0x support):

```
operator()(const A&, const B&)
operator()(const A&, B&)
operator()(A&, const B&)
operator()(A&, B&)
```

to forward perfectly.

Here is a link that describe the perfect-forwarding problem in details: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1385.htm

Imperfect forwarding will *eventually* cause you:

- compilation errors in the case of non-const or const reference solutions (like boost::bind)
- unexpected copies in the case of by-value solutions

Comment: Would you please give me a concrete example in which imperfect forwarding does pose a problem (such as compilation errors)? (A very simple one would be enough and appreciated!)

Comment: There is a simple "motivating example" in the link i've provided. Imperfect forwarding will at worse cause compilation errors or unexpected copies of the arguments (the first in boost::bind)

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you have the following generic function (all it does is pass arguments (called "forwarding") to the inner function `callme`):

```
template <typename T> void f(T& t)
{
    callme(t);
}
```

Now, pretend that the definition of `callme` looks like this: `void callme(const int& i)`.
The problem is that `callme(1)` will work, but `f(1)` will not (this is because rvalues do not bind to non-const references). To solve this, you need to change `f` to: `f(const T& t)`.
However, this introduces a new problem. If `callme` is defined like this: `void callme(int& i)`, you will get a compile error. The solution is to make two overloads for `f` to take both `f(const T& t)` and `f(T& t)`.

Now, the above situation works fine when a function only takes a single argument. However, imagine a function that takes two arguments, you have to make 4 overloads:

```
f(const T1&, const T2&)
f(const T1&, T2&)
f(T1&, const T2&)
f(T1&, T2&)
```

[In this article on msdn](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/02/03/rvalue-references-c-0x-features-in-vc10-part-2.aspx), it mentions that for `tr1::bind`, for 5 arguments, a total of 63 overloads was needed!
What I have just explained is called the [forwarding problem](http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=forwarding+problem&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aja%3aofficial&hl=ja&client=firefox-a) which has been solved in `C++11` using perfect forwarding and rvalue references.

Quote from Boost Site:

`The library chooses a small subset: for up to two arguments, it provides the const overloads in full, for arities of three and more it provides a single additional overload with all of the arguments taken by const reference.`

Comment: I just edited my question (an example added). Please take a look at it at your convenience. (BTW, is a message like this supposed to be written here, or should be sent in other way?)

Comment: @updogliu: I edited my answer. The message you wrote is fine.